# In Cakephp 3.6 How do I get the size and type of an image to send it by form?

Tags: forms, image, cakephp-3.0

How do I get the size and type of an image to send it by form?

Well that, I want to save in the table of images the size and type of an image that is uploaded through a form. With Ajax, I can recover those data, but to pass them to PHP I can only do when sending the form, also directly with PHP:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
          $isData = $this->request->getdata();
          $imagene->imagen = $isData['image_path'];
          $imagene->tipo = $isData['type']
          $imagene->tamano = $isData['size'];
          ...
```

But I want to do it before sending the form, which is when the insertion is done in the database.

Form:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($imagene, ['novalidate', 'id' => 'addimageform', 'class' => 'form addimageform']); ?>    
<?= $this->Form->control('imagen', ['type' => 'file', 'class' => 'imagen-addimage']); ?>
<?= $this->Form->hidden('tipo', ['value' => $tipo, 'class' => 'tipo-addimage']); ?>
<?= $this->Form->hidden('$tipo', ['value' => $size, 'class' => 'tamano-addimage']); ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Subir imagen', ['id' => 'submit', 'class' => 'submit-addimage']); ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Omitir', ['id' => 'omitir', 'class' => 'omitir-addimage', 'redirect' => ['controller' => 'administracion', 'action' => 'index']]); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Now I see that if I do a debug of $isData, the field: "imagen" does not appear:

```
    'tabla' => 'users',
    'id_tabla' => '22',
    'tipo' => '',
    'tamano' => ''
```

**UPDATING**

I've changed things in the form and the controller:

**form:**

```
<?= $this->Form->create($imagene, ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'novalidate', 'id' => 'addimageform', 'class' => 'form addimageform']); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->control('imagen', ['type' => 'file', 'class' => 'imagen-addimage']); ?>
    <div class="centrar-submit">
      <?= $this->Form->button('Subir imagen', ['id' => 'submit', 'class' => 'submit-addimage']); ?>
      <?= $this->Form->button('Omitir', ['id' => 'omitir', 'class' => 'omitir-addimage', 'redirect' => ['controller' => 'administracion', 'action' => 'index']]); ?>
    </div>
    <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function add($table, $idTable) {
      $imagene = $this->Imagenes->newEntity();
      if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $isData = $this->request->getdata();
        debug($this->request->getData('imagen')); // <---- Is null
        debug($isData); // <---- Is empty
        ...
```

Why? I don't know.

Comment: You want to know the size of the image that the user is going to upload through your form, before they upload it?

Comment: Use javascript to get those values as soon as an image is choosen in your „imagen“ form control. Then you can do stuff again with JavaScript, before submitting the image. Once you submit the server side php will execute and you can only „interact“ with it, if you are using a series of pages or using javascript again to call the server and execute php code and interact with responses.

Comment: @GregSchmidt yes

Comment: I update the information, I've changed things in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should mentioned what type of form you used. That is file type you should use

```
echo $this->Form->create($article, ['type' => 'file']);
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: I already proved it: 

´<?= $this->Form->create($imagene, ['type' => 'file']); ?>
<?= $this->Form->file('image', ['id' => 'image', 'name' => 'image'); ?>´

Comment: No, the problem continues, I have tried to follow the instructions of 

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html

"Changing the HTTP Method for a Form, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I update the information, I've changed things in the controller.